# How to concatenate multiple VARCHAR columns into single CLOB or LONG column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

So I have several VARCHAR(4000) columns that are filled to the MAX in my Oracle SQL Table. I am trying to concatenate/combine them into a single column (LONG or CLOB). How do I do this? I've tried concatentate and obviously that doesn't work... I receive 'a result of string concatenation is too long' error.

I've tried the following: 
   select id, (comment_1 || comment_2)
   from table
   group by id;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to use the [`DBMS_LOB` package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/d_lob.htm#TTPLP600).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `select id, to_clob(comment1) || comment2 from table group by id`. But generally better way is modify the database design and add clob column into the table.

Comment: yes! that's what i just figured out. I was able to add a dummy CLOB column with no data and the function works if i insert that column first as part of my concatenated string. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @icerabbit - you don't need to add a dummy CLOB column; you can simply `select to_clob('') || comment1 || ....` if you don't want to have to wrap `comment1` itself within `to_clob()`.